# Reading from pipe into buffer character by character/find the size of data in pipe

Tags: c++, operating-system, pipe

I'm currently working with pipes using `"unistd.h"` and `"sys/wait.h"` for my OS homework. I'm trying to implement graph pipe.

Since in graph pipe there is a possibility that output of a process can be sent to more than one process as an input, I need to store it in a buffer and send from it in a loop.

To read output from process, I use `read()` function. The problem is that since the number of characters in an output is variable, either I need to read it one character by one or somehow find the size of output.

I'm trying to do the first option. Here is my code

```
string buffer;
char temp[1];
while (/*condition*/)
{
    read (pipe[0], temp, 1);
    buffer.push_back (temp[0]);
}
```

My question is what is the condition that must be inside of loop?

P.S. If second option is easier then how can I check the size of output of a process in a pipe?

Answer (score 2):

The condition is really the return of the `read` call:

```
while (read(...) == 1) { ... }
```

Also don't forget the address-of operator, you can use that instead of declaring `temp` as an array:

```
char temp;
while (read(pipe[0], &temp, sizeof(temp)) == sizeof(temp)) { ... }
```

Comment: it causes an infinite loop

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev It shouldn't, unless the writing end of the pipe never closes its end. When (if) it closes its end of the pipe and the reader has read the remaining data then `read` should return zero. And of course `read` will return `-1` on error, both of these values very different from `sizeof(temp)`.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev Another possibility is that the writing end simply isn't writing anything. Then `read` will block (i.e. it will not return), which might seem like an infinite loop. Open your favorite search engine and search for e.g. "posix non blocking descriptor" to learn about how to make a file-descriptor non-blocking and how to use it.